# Bezout-Style Theorem for two surfaces - Interpolation of Points in a General Position

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Suppose we have a polynomial $P$ with real coefficients over, say 5 variables i.e. over  $\mathbb R[x,y,z,u,v]$. Further let us suppose the degree of $P$ is at most $N^{\alpha}$.

Let us also consider another polynomial $Q$ over $\mathbb R[x,y,z]$.

If we know that a certain $N^{\beta}$ points of $Z(Q)$ in "general position" are contained in the zero set of P, $Z(P)$, when can we say that $Z(Q)$ is contained entirely within $Z(P)$? What relationship must $\beta$ and $\alpha$ satisfy?

Intuition would suggest that such a condition exists, because we can think about $\alpha$ very small and $\beta$ large. Then it should follow that the polynomial doesn't have degree high enough to "bend" (interpolate) into each point, and thus would have to be zero everywhere.

I am looking in particular for literature that does a similar type of interpolation.

In fact the sort of theorem I am looking for is something of the form:
If $Q$ is not a factor of $P$, then $Z(P,Q)$ contains at most $\deg P \deg Q$ "objects", be they lines, curves, or points.
The goal here is to have a condition that forces us to conclude $Z(Q) \subset Z(P)$.

For example for $F,G \in \mathbb R[x,y,z]$ we have if $F,G$ do not have a common factor, then the number of lines in $Z(F,G) \subset \mathbb R^3$ is at most $(\deg P )(\deg Q)$. [Theorem 6.7 - Polynomial Methods in Combinatorics - Guth]

"General Position" := Not too many points on any one lower dimensional variety, for example, not all fall on a line. Condition required as otherwise this seems unsolvable because we could get infinitely many points in $Z(P)$ all the time.